# Problema a realizar pedidos á API

Tags: api, rest, zend, postman

Estou a tentar realizar pedidos a uma API: EGOI mas obtenho um erro.

O pedido é o seguinte:

http://api.e-goi.com/v2/rest.php?method=checklogin&apikey=minhaAPIKEY

Sabem como passo parâmetros para o ZEND?

Obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Egoi_Api generator="zend" version="1.0">
    <checklogin>
        <ERROR>NO_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_AND_APIKEY</ERROR>
        <status>success</status>
    </checklogin>
</Egoi_Api>
```

Comment: Já tentou dar uma procurada [aqui](https://api-docs.e-goi.com/)?

Comment: Sim, já verifiquei toda a documentação e nada :/

Answer (score 0):

Voce deve ter os dados de acesso(username, password ou token), faça uma requisição para a url da api com os dados pelo seu controller

```
use Zend\Http\Client;

$client = new Client();
$client->setUri('http://api.fooo.com');
$client->setMethod('POST');
$client->setParameterPost(array(
   'username' => 'bar',
   'password' => 'bar',
));

$response = $client->send();

if ($response->isSuccess()) {
   // successo
}
```